# Laravel 5.2 Unit Test 404

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5

I have this simple test set up and I'm trying to find out why when I run this test I get this error message. When I visit myapp.app in my browser I see the welcome page for the install of Laravel 5.2.

```
There were 2 failures:

1) ExampleTest::testExample
A request to [myapp.app] failed. Received status code [404].
```

Parent Test Class

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'myapp.app';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

Default Example Test From Laravel Installation

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
            ->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [post](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/571)

Comment: I'm not using the API middleware

Answer (score 2):

The problem as I was taught from a friend that using xdebug I can enter into the code and find out what is happening.

The reason for this was because in the testcase file and the baseURL needed to be set properly.

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://myapp.app';
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by returning the `APP_URL` variable of `.env` file to original value:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Most times, I use 'http://localhost'. Have you tried that?

Comment: I later found out what the issue is but you are close.

Comment: So, @user3732216 add an answer to help other people ;)

Comment: I did 26 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble, but my problem was that I connected extra. api modules to the main api.php, like this:

```php
Route::get(//some routes)
...

require_once('entity.php');
```

please don't do that